# Prevent dot-release upgrade of RHEL while still patching flaws

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5

I am running RHEL 5.4, and cannot update to 5.5 or 5.6 because of a restriction by the vendor of a software package I need to run on the server. However, it seems that most of the tools that manage software updates will silently upgrade the system. Specifically the "Software Update" applet (pup), as well as the push system on the RHN (applying errata, etc), have the effect of upgrading to the latest dot release. What is the best practice to stay on top of security updates, but not to move beyond RHEL 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of you who may be interested I believe I have the answer.  Add the following line to /etc/yum.conf

```
exclude=redhat-release*
```

I also want to restrict upgrades to kernel RPMs and libc, so my line actually looks like this:

```
exclude=redhat-release*,kernel*,glibc*
```